# Is it possible to get remote javascript file to execute on the server before being embedded in page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

Ok there is a remote server called VENDOR_API_SERVER that i'm hitting in order to fetch various data. I have an app running on MY_APP_SERVER containing a javascript file that uses AJAX to handle requests and responses from to/from VENDOR_API_SERVER. I then have MY_USER_FACING_APP that embeds the aforementioned javascript file via `<script>` tag. All 3 apps run on different hosts. When the javascript file makes it's REST call to VENDOR_API_SERVER, I would like it to be executed from MY_APP_SERVER and then make the response data available to the page on MY_USER_FACING_APP. With the configuration below, the javascript file is being executed from MY_USER_FACING_APP, which is what i'm trying to avoid.

**req.js on MY_APP_SERVER**
*URL (example): http://my_app_server.io/js/req.js*

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "http://vendor_api_server.io/api/dothis", function() {
    console.log('request made');
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log('success - check log');
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log('fail - wassup');
  })
```

**results.html on MY_USER_FACING_APP**
*URL (example): http://my_user_facing_server.io/search/results.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Results</title>
    <script src="http://my_app_server.io/js/req.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Results</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I that javascript file can't be executed by MY_APP_SERVER before making the response data available to MY_USER_FACING_APP, I'm thinking there has to be some secure, elegant way to use MY_APP_SERVER as a proxy/delegate but am having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Or what I'm trying to do could be just a giant hack at its core... i don't know as i'm quite new to this type of development.

Anyone with any insight and/or wisdom to impart?

Comment: Why not make a server side request in YOUR_APP_SERVER instead of a javascript request?

Comment: Why does the script reside on my_app_server instead of the my_user_facing_app which it is part of? What is special about it? What's the my_app_server good for at all?

Comment: Yes, whatever the script does, your server can do as well. But not simply by executing a script that was meant for a browser environment.

Comment: @Bergi - the javaScript I'm trying to execute is a plugin I'm developing. Anyone who chooses to purchase the plugin would just embed it via script tag within their app. It in order for me to maintain control and push out updates to every user, it must reside on MY_APP_SERVER.

Comment: And what's special about my_user_facing_app then? It seems to be just another webpage using that plugin. Why would it need to execute the plugin on the server side, unlike every other page with the plugin?

Comment: But yes, in general I agree... I was overthinking it. I can use a server-side page to make the actual REST call (probably using CURL) and then print out the response JSON to be returned to MY_USER_FACING_APP or CUSTOMERS_USER_FACING_APP. The only problem I have here is that the HTTP_ORIGIN will show CUSTOMERS_USER_FACING_APP when I need it to be MY_APP_SERVER. Any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have the javascript plugin file make an AJAX request to a PHP page residing on MY_APP_SERVER. That page in turn uses cURL to make the REST call to VENDOR_API_SERVER and sends the returned data back to the javascript/plugin file so it can be manipulated and displayed in the DOM on the app running on CUSTOMERS_USER_FACING_APP.

**plugin.js on MY_APP_SERVER**
*URL (example): http://my_app_server.io/plugin.js*

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "http://my_app_server.io/curl.php", function() {
    console.log('request made');
})
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log('success - check log');
    console.log('response data: %o', data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log('fail - wassup!');
  })
```

**curl.php on MY_APP_SERVER**
*URL (example): http://my_app_server.io/curl.php*

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://vendor_api_server.io/api/dothis");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");


// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print $server_output;

?>
```

**results.html on CUSTOMERS_USER_FACING_APP**
*URL (example): http://customers_user_facing_server.io/search/results.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Results</title>
    <script src="http://my_app_server.io/js/req.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Results</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm still not convinced that this is the best way, but it *does* achieve my goal of keeping the origin of the requests to the API coming from MY_APP_SERVER and not CUSTOMERS_USER_FACING_APP.

Please feel free to shoot holes in anything I've done here. It seems very "work-around ish" to me. I'd love to hear any thoughts on a less jinky solution.